# convert netscape cookies to LWP perl

Tags: perl, cookies, lwp, netscape

I am trying to convert cookies in Netscape format that were exported from firefox to LWP format to use them in another library that wants cookies only in LWP format. I am using this script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use LWP;
use HTTP::Cookies;
use Data::Dumper;

my $in =  'cookies.txt';
my $out = 'cookies.lwp';
my $c = HTTP::Cookies::Netscape->new;
$c->load($in);
print Dumper($c);
$c->HTTP::Cookies::save($out);

exit;
```

But I am getting empty LWP cookie file, and Dumper prints

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 '' => 'cookies.txt',
                 'COOKIES' => {}
               }, 'HTTP::Cookies::Netscape' );
```

Why HTTP:Cookies cant read my cookies file in Netscape format?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the file formats? I've actually had some success with 'just' loading a `cookies.txt` straight into LWP.

Comment: Also: Might be useful to reformat the cookies at export: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/export-cookies/

Comment: Thanks, with this extention everything worked ok

Answer (score 0):

With this extension I have exported cookies and everything got converted correctly:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/export-cookies/